# How to make life in toast by default in primevue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

I'm using PrimeVue and I have a toast component.

```
  <Toast>
<template #message="props" >
  <div class="flex justify-between w-full">
    <div class="flex-column w-full ml-2">
      <span class="text-base font-medium">{{
        defineType(props.message.type).title
      }}</span>
      <span class="text-sm">{{ props.message.text }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I call it with the method

```
toast.add({ type: 'error', text: 'Инн не обнаружен'});
```

But how do you make life the default? I don’t want to pass it as a parameter every time, but I want to make 3000 the default.
I don't like the setTimeout solution

Comment: Use custom helper that wraps around toast.add. The implementation is really barebone https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/components/lib/toastservice/ToastService.js